# Control Water: Whirlpool option usable with other options?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [Control Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/control-water) spell (PHB p. 227) provides several options for manipulating water in some volume. The Flood, Part Water and Redirect Flow options all explicitly state that the effect lasts until the spell ends or another option is chosen. However, the Whirlpool option does not mention this. Clearly, the whirlpool should go away when the spell ends, and the effect implies that it lasts for more than one round. But what happens if you pick another effect? Does the Whirlpool remain even if you Part Water through it? RAW implies it would by my reading, although that seems to defy common sense.

Is Whirlpool not going away when you pick another effect an intentional part of the spell, or an oversight which should be corrected?

Also, creatures can be caught in the vortex for more than one turn, implying its continued existence, but the part of the effect describing creatures and objects being pulled towards the vortex doesn't state that it continues each turn. Is this suction effect once-off, or should it continue each round?

Comment: Other questions about the Whirlpool option of the *control water* spell: [How does the Whirlpool application of the Control Water spell work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/175362/33569), [When do objects take damage from being inside the Whirlpool option of the Control Water spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159509/33569), [How large is the whirlpool when a Nereid uses their Shape Water (Control Water) feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/189088/33569)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whirlpool effect makes no mention of the effect ending. Since it doesn't make sense that it would continue after the spell ends, It seems to be an oversight.

All the other effect say the effect ends when "the spell ends or you choose a different effect."

If we take precedent from the other effects, then it would end when the spell ends or you choose another effect.

The pull is a property of the vortex. The next sentence gives a DC for swimming away from the vortex. As long as it exists, anything in the water within 25 ft will be drawn toward it.